# weekly moving average from current_date to the last 52 weeks

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, functions

I'm a new head to the mysql programming. I have to write a procedure for calculating a weekly moving average grouped by week from 'monday-friday'.

Criteria is : current_date is the end date. start date should be either previous 52 weeks if available or if the number of weeks is less then the moving average should be calculated till the available date.

Comment: You've described what you have to do, but didn't mention at all, what the problem is. I don't see, why you would need a procedure for this, a normal query would do. Regarding your last paragraph, don't worry about this. You either have data for this timespan or you don't. MySQL will calculate the average for the data you have, not calculate an average for missing data.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table\G;

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I thought either a stored procedure/ function would be easier to store as I need this process to be run every end-of-week. Also, I think function would be more reusable . If my perception on this requirement to use functions is correct, please guide me.

Comment: This site is not about teaching everything from the ground up, it helps with specific problems. Google for the difference between a procedure and a function.

Comment: Check out my first comment - we need/want your table structure to answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g(f(date)) AS 'week of',
       AVG(...) AS 'moving average'
    FROM tbl
    WHERE date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 52 WEEK
    GROUP BY f(date)
```

Where `f()` is a function that turns a date (or datetime or timestamp) into a number.  Something like `FLOOR((TO_DAYS(date) - 3) / 7)`, where the `3` is chosen based on what day a week "starts" on.  (I doubt if '3' is correct.)  `g()` is the inverse:  `FROM_DAYS((x * 7) + 3)`.  Test:

```
mysql> SELECT                            NOW(), 
                          FLOOR((TO_DAYS(now()) - 3) / 7) AS 'f(now)',
              FROM_DAYS( (FLOOR((TO_DAYS(now()) - 3) / 7) * 7) + 3) AS 'g(f(now))';
+---------------------+--------+------------+
| NOW()               | f(now) | g(f(now))  |
+---------------------+--------+------------+
| 2016-05-24 17:13:54 | 105210 | 2016-05-24 |
+---------------------+--------+------------+
```